# Objective-C: how to init NSMutableDictionary with Array?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an Array, which consists of `object,key,object,key,object,key`.

How to init NSMutableDictionary with this array?

I found methods for separated arrays of keys(ArrayOfKeys) and objects(ArrayOfObjects), but not for this mixed Array.

also `ObjectsAndKeys` maybe help, but i don't know how.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i < [array length] - 1; i += 2)
{
    [dictionary setObject:[array objectAtIndex:i+1] forKey:[array objectAtIndex: i]];
}
```

Comment: @loldop Have a look at this blog post: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html

Answer (score 2):

Just create two arrays: keysArray (odd indexes) and valuesArray (even indexes) and use `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesArray forKeys:keysArray]`

You can do this with a single for loop...

Comment: i know, but i want to avoid tricks like this. I think, that Apple libraries are more flexible, oh

Comment: @loldop In this particular case there is no initializer that does what you want. You'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: Flexibility doesn't mean giving anything you want

Comment: @Jun1st it is strange, that i have method `ObjectsAndKeys` and doesn't  have method `ObjectsAndKeysFromOneArray`. i want this method, cause it  simple to realization and simple to read.

Comment: @loldop Apple would do the same thing in their own apps, it's the best way to do it. You only iterate the array once and the dictionary is created with the right capacity instead of being extended like Jun1st suggested (slower).

Comment: @loldop Why don't you do a simple category, it would take what? 2 minutes?

Comment: @fbernardo what do you mean with `simple category`?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: Categories are a way to add methods to an existing class. You want to add a method to NSMutableDictionary like +[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithArrayOfObjectsAndKeys:].

Comment: @loldop, it's definitely simple. but it takes time to do a thing, no matter how simple it is. Frameworks are built by developers, and developers are lazy:)